# Convert datetime to local time

Tags: python

I'm doing a parse from string ISO8601 to a datetime and it's working. Now I want to return datetime on localtime but my code is returning same timestamp from input:

```
def format_string_to_timestamp(dt,  defaultTimezone='America/Sao_Paulo'):
  origin_dt = datetime.strptime(dt, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')  
  tz_local = pytz.timezone (defaultTimezone)  
  dt_local = origin_dt.astimezone(tz_local).replace(tzinfo=None)  
  print(dt)
  print(dt_local)
  print(origin_dt)
  return dt_local.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
  # example input: 2019-02-25T17:58:53.753
```

What is missing to return dt_local as America/Sao_Paulo timezone?

Comment: Your code works for me.

Comment: It should return -3 hours. My code keep returning `2019-02-25 17:58:53` instead of `2019-02-25 14:58:53`

Comment: So when you print `dt_local` it is `2019-02-25 17:58:53`?

Comment: Yes! It should be `2019-02-25 14:58:53`